# Границы ячеек HTML

Tags: html

Как отобразить только нижний край ячейки в таблице?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```css
td {
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr><td>A</td><td>B</td></tr>
  <tr><td>C</td><td>D</td></tr>
</table>
```